# How to avoid printing of arrow keys while taking input from terminal in C?

Tags: c, linux, shell, input, terminal

```c
//input.c
#include <stdio.h>
char name[20];
scanf("%s", name);
```

When the above program is compiled and run from a terminal, it takes input:

```sh
$ gcc ./input.c
$ ./a.out
MyNameHwre
```

When I try to fix that typo from "Hwre" to "Here", by pressing left arrow, this happends:

```
MyNameHwre^[[D
```

The following only seems to appear in `bash` shells. In Windows Command Prompt, the following doesn't happen - and we can just use left arrows to go back and change "w" to "e". How can we have `bash` not print those sequences for arrows, backspace, or any control sequences?

Comment: `$ rlwrap ./a.out` ... see https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap

Comment: The Windows terminal driver manages processes function keys automatically, the Linux terminal driver doesn't -- applications have to do it themselves. You can use the `readline` library.